# How to create a dictionary using user id?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm a beginner in programming and I've got an impediment, so basically I want to create something like this

```
set = {
        user_id_1 : 'result_user_id_1', 
        user_id_2 : 'result_user_id_2', 
        user_id_3 : 'result_user_id_3' 
      }
```

Simplified I want each user to have it's score in the dictionary.

Result is from mytags (teamplatetags) and it's a score that all the users are giving a score for eachother in order to obtain a final score.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


VALOARE = (
    (1, "Nota 1"),
    (2, "Nota 2"),
    (3, "Nota 3"),
    (4, "Nota 4"),
    (5, "Nota 5"),
    (6, "Nota 6"),
    (7, "Nota 7"),
    (8, "Nota 8"),
    (9, "Nota 9"),
    (10, "Nota 10"),
)


class Punctaj(models.Model):
    acordat_de = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0)
    acordat_catre = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0, related_name="acordat_catre")
    nota = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=VALOARE)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    data = dict()
    data['users']=User.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        for key in request.POST:
            if 'nota_' in key:
                nota_acordata = Punctaj.objects.filter(acordat_de=request.user, acordat_catre__id=key.split('_')[1]).first()
                if nota_acordata:
                    nota_acordata.nota = request.POST.get(key)
                    nota_acordata.save()

                else:
                    Punctaj.objects.create(acordat_de=request.user, acordat_catre_id=key.split('_')[1], nota=request.POST.get(key))
                    messages.success(request,"Successfully Voted")

        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, "login/home.html", data)
```

mytags.py - templatetag

```
@register.simple_tag
def results(user):
    suma = Punctaj.objects.filter(acordat_catre=user).aggregate(punctaj=Sum('nota')).get("punctaj")
    count = Punctaj.objects.filter(acordat_catre=user).count()
    if not suma:
        result = 0
    else:
        result = int(suma)/count
    return result
```

Template

```
<form class ="nota" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> User </th>
                <th> Nota finala </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        {% for fotbalist in users %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ fotbalist.username }}</td>
                <td>
                    <p>{% results fotbalist %}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), looks like you just want the average "nota" for each user?

```
User.objects.annotate(score=Avg('acordat_catre__nota'))
```

The resulting list of users will now have an attribute "score", one plus for this approached, compared to the template tag, is that it will reduce the number of queries you make considerably

Your template is now

```
    {% for fotbalist in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ fotbalist.username }}</td>
            <td>
                <p>{{ fotbalist.score }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

If you really just want the dictionary you need to do

```
dict(User.objects.annotate(score=Avg('acordat_catre__nota')).values_list('id', 'score'))
```

Comment: No, no, i've done the average and everything now i just want a dictionary that takes each users id and score like this:  set = { user_id : score, user_id: score } but what you showed me helps aswell to simplify my work

Comment: The way you calculate the average score is inefficient, if you have 1000 users you will end up running 2000 queries

Comment: I understand i am editing right now the way you showed me, any way you can help me with the dictionary?

Comment: So instead of if request.method == "post" the home function will be like this?  
    def home(request):
        data = dict()
        data['users']=User.objects.all()               User.objects.annotate(score=Avg('acordat_catre__nota'))
        return render(request, "login/home.html", data)

Comment: You just need to change the single line where you add users to the context. `data['users'] = User.objects.annotate(score=Avg('acordat_catre__nota'))`